# Error: Error creating IAM User abc@123.com: EntityAlreadyExists: User with name abc@123.com already exists

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I have a Central AWS account where I am creating users so that I can assign Developer and Testers roles to them.

**Below is my structure:-**

Central Account (UserA, UserB, UserC etc got created)

Account I have:- Account1, Account2,Account3,Account4

Now my scenario is:-

```
I need UserA and UserB to have Developer roles in Account1
I need UserA and UserC to have Tester roles in Account1 and Account2
```

While achieving this I am getting below error:-

```
Error: Error creating IAM User abc@123.com: EntityAlreadyExists: User with name abc@123.com already exists.
```

Source block

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "group" {
  name = "developer"
}
resource "aws_iam_group_membership" "group" {
  count = "${length(var.username)}"
  name  = "developer_group_membership"
  users = ["${element(aws_iam_user.user.*.name, count.index)}"]
  group = aws_iam_group.group.name
}
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  count         = length(var.username)
  name          = element(var.username, count.index)
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "iam_user_application_developer_role_policy"
  description = "IAM Policy"
  policy      = data.template_file.iam_policy_template.rendered
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "iam_policy_attach" {
  count      = length(var.username)
  user       = element(aws_iam_user.user.*.name, count.index)
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the user already exists. Had you already created the users before running this? If so you need to import them in to your state file. If not then you need to look at what you're doing with state. Either way, the content of this question can't help solve your issue.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes.. I have already created the user in Central account. I need the same user to be part of Account1 as well as account2.